# SQL query to get columns and records of that columns using like operator

Tags: sql

I have a table as show below the bold words are column names

**KEYWORD PART1_D1  PART1_D2  PART1_D3  PART1_D4  PART2_D5**
y          1        0       0         0         1
Chinese     3       2       2         1         1
Tokyo      1        0       0         0         1
Japan      1        0       0         0         1
Beijing  0        1       0         0         0
Shangh      0       0       1         0         0

i wrote a query as below

Select COLumn_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'sample' and COLumn_NAME like '%part1%'
the out put is iam getting only columns as shown below

**COLumn_NAME**
part1_d1
part1_d2
part1_d3
part1_d4

but i want to get records also from the table like my output should be as show below 

Keyword     PART1_D1   PART1_D2     PART1_D3      PART1_D4
y          1            0         0            0
Chinese      3          2         2            1
Tokyo        1          0         0            0
Japan       1           0         0            0
Beijing     0           1         0            0
Shangh       0          0         1            0

Comment: You mean, you want to get column names in first row of resultset?

Comment: Yes i want to retrieve column name and their respective records also plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the column names ahead of time, just UNION in an extra record. Of course, then your resultset will have to have all character fields:

```
Select 'KEYWORD' as KEYWORD, 'PART1_D1' as PART1_D1, 'PART1_D2' as PART1_D2, 
  'PART1_D3' as PART1_D3, 'PART1_D4' as PART1_D4, 'PART2_D5' as PART2_D5,
UNION
Select KEYWORD, cast(PART1_D1 as varchar(50), cast(PART1_D2 as varchar(50), 
  cast(PART1_D3 as varchar(50), cast(PART1_D4 as varchar(50), 
  cast(PART2_D5 as varchar(50)
From sample
```